# Is there a way to display text that I get from my View.xaml.cs to my View.xaml in MAUI.NET?

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui

I am trying to figure out how to display text of totalClients that I get from my View.xaml.cs on my View.xaml.

View.xaml

```
<VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">

                <Label Text="{Binding TotalClients}" TextColor="{x:StaticResource BankrWhite}" FontSize="100" FontFamily="SFProDisplayMedium" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" CharacterSpacing="12.8"/>
                <Label TextColor="{x:StaticResource BankrYellow}" Text="total clients" FontSize="24" FontFamily="SFProDisplaySemibold" TextTransform="Uppercase" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" CharacterSpacing="4.32"/>          

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

View.xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        int clients = App.ClientRepo.GetClientsTotal();

        TotalClients.Text = clients.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: your code doesn't make sense `TotalClients` is expected to be a xaml element identifier from code perspective, and at the same time a property from xaml perspective. Have you read the basic xaml docs related to data binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can assign values directly to an element by assigning it an `x:Name`

```
<Label x:Name="lblTotalClients" ...
```

then in the code behing

```
lblTotalClients.Text = clients.ToString();
```

however, [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm) is generally the prefered approach